# When to spell out non-alphanumeric characters?

Tags: orthography, capitalization, hyphenation

If a term contains non-alphanumeric characters, when (if ever) should these characters be spelled out? For example:

> C++   written as   **C Plus Plus**
>
> C#      written as   **C-Sharp**

If they are spelled out, what are the conventions regarding capitalization and hyphens (e.g. **C Plus Plus** or **C-plus-plus**)?

Comment: I suggest there's never really any reason to write those long forms except in programming code, where "macros" such as **#ifdef __cplusplus** need to avoid including symbols that might confuse the compiler's parsing logic.

Comment: The only other reason I can think of for spelling them out is to indicate pronunciation ("C#, pronounced C-sharp not C-hash"; "C++, pronounced C-plus-plus not C-add-add")

Comment: And the third only reason is for tags or keywords where you can't search for punctuation.

Comment: A fourth only reason would be when explaining the origin and meaning of such a term.

Comment: Enough already! We don't need a fifth reason!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I'm not stepping out of line, but since the comments contained several good answers, I thought it worthwhile to group them together into a properly credited answer. Currently it seems the community has found four reasons to spell out non-alphanumeric characters:

1. [FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers) noted that programming code can require spelling out such symbols to avoid creating problems during the parsing phase of a compiler/interpreter.
2. [Waggers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/4796/waggers) added that spelling out symbols can clarify pronunciation (e.g. "C#" as "C-sharp" rather than "C-hash" or "C-pound")
3. [Hugo](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/9001/hugo) mentioned the concept of avoiding reserved characters in a tagging/keyword/categorization system.
4. [Jay](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/13140/jay) added that explaining the origin and meaning of such a term could require spelling it out. I think there's a lot of overlap between this and Waggers' answer about pronunciation.